# C# - If data from database table column has country name then display "text on datatable"

Tags: c#, sql

I was able to retrieve data from SQL Server database and return it in json format. Now I have this region table which has the region and country name on it.

Now when retrieving data from this table which has country name, I want to display only the let say airport on that country only one airport.

```
public void GetAllRooms()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblResortsRooms.intResortID, tblResortsRooms.strRoomType,tblResortsRooms.strDescription, tblRegions.strRegion FROM ((tblResortsRooms INNER JOIN tblResorts ON tblResorts.intResortID = tblResortsRooms.intResortID) INNER JOIN tblRegions ON tblRegions.intRegionID = tblResorts.intResortID);";

        con.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        // NEED HELP HERE
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
                if (dr["strRegion"].ToString().Contains("Philiphines"))
                {
                    // need help here to for that table column stregion to display airport only one airport for that country
                }
        }

        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        Context.Response.Write(JSONString);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not clear.  What is the problem you are trying to solve and how have you tried to solve it?

Comment: @Brody i have updated my code if you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

You have a datatable and are then converting that into JSON. Sounds like you want to query your datatable. Best way to do that is on the table and not on the JSON string.

For ex - `var string = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("columnName");`

Best of luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

No Worries i have found the soultion to my own code :

below is the code that works :

```
            var city = "Manilla";
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if(dr["strRegion"].ToString().Contains("Philipines") )
                {
                    dr["strRegion"] = city;
                }
            }
```